# algorithm for fitting different sized circles into a square

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms, circles, packing-problem

I have the following question. I want to stack differently sized circles into a square/rectangle in a pyramid pattern and write code that can calculate the amount of circles in it.  Kind of like this.

[image]

But I don't know how to go about it. Thanks to a question I asked a few days ago I was able to understand and use this formula that calculates the amount of circles vertically stacked if the circles were all the same size. (d = diameter, a = length of the square)

[image]

How would I go about adapting this to different diameters?

To clarify, I want to create this kind of pattern but with differently shaped circles.

[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added another picture for clarification. I want to stack circles of varying diameters in that kind of pattern in a square and I do not know how I can accomplish that or whether or not this is even possible.